# Download image from new window on click in php

Tags: php, javascript, image, browser, download

I want to download the image from the new window of browser. Means When I click on image it should appear in new window and there is button to download it.

Till Now I am able to download it on single click instead of open in new window means when I click on image a browser pop up generates to open or save image. But I want to first open image in new window the download button to downlaod.

This is my code which I am using.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    //Please give the Path like this
    $file = $_GET['file'];

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add two `$_GET` variables, one to check if `file` is specified, another for `download`. For file, just put the image using `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. Then, put a download button and `onclick`, pass a `$_GET['download']` which'll allow users to download using the same code as posted in question.

Comment: @DreamEater can you Please give me the code .